# JS: Associative array access over variable?

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

after progging php since 3 years, im hanging at javascript. Is it possible to get value of an assoziative array with a variable? Example:

```
var a = new Array();
a["ANDI"] = "USER";
var test = "ANDI";

alert(a[test]);
```

Any suggestions, how I could workaround that? Maybe with objects?

Thx for help!

Comment: You don't even need Array for that, new Object() will do.

Comment: That's actually a misuse of `Array`, since arrays are really meant to be numerically indexed. `new Object()` or just `{}` is the right choice.

Comment: Workaround what? Your code works.

Comment: @Matt Keep in mind they're coming from PHP. PHP doesn't have objects, only "associative" arrays. A data type made for using *words* to store data is a completely foreign concept for a PHP programmer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Arrays are indexed by numbers.  Objects have properties that can be accessed by name.

```
var myContainer = {
  'User': 'Andy'
};

var key = 'User';

myContainer[key]; // Returns 'Andy'.
```

Comment: +1 for object over array, and object literal notation. Quoted keys are optional (unless you want to use a string which is not a valid JavaScript identifier).

Comment: Quoted keys are optional, but I use them out of habit from Python.  It also prevents these pitfalls:  `var myContainer = { my.name: 'Value', 'My Name': 'Val2' }`.

Answer (score 3):

Yup. That should alert USER.

But JavaScript has objects. If you want to do that, you'd probably want..

```
var a = {
    "ANDI": "USER"
};
```

For more details of JavaScript's object notations, check out [JSON.org](http://json.org).

Answer (score 2):

Sure, the code you have shown works perfectly fine and prints `USER` as expected. Live demo: http://jsfiddle.net/htnPe/